# why is google chart column not generating in angular app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am adding the Google column chart I Pasted some code from AGC to my page but why is it not generating the chart?

**Bar.cshtml**

```
<div google-chart chart="myChartObject" width:100%;"></div>
    @section scripts{
        <script src="~/Scripts/Charts/BarCharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-google-chart/0.1.0/ng-google-chart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>}
```

**MyApp.cshtml**

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
app.filter('ctime', function(){

    return function(jsonDate){

        var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
        return date;
    }   
})
```

**Javfile.Js**

```
   var app = angular.module("MyApp", ['googlechart']);
                    app.controller("GenericChartCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.myChartObject = {};

        $scope.myChartObject.type = "ColumnChart";

        $scope.onions = [
            { v: "Onions" },
            { v: 3 },
        ];

        $scope.myChartObject.data = {
            "cols": [
                { id: "t", label: "Topping", type: "string" },
                { id: "s", label: "Slices", type: "number" }
            ], "rows": [ {
c: [ { v: "Mushrooms" }, { v: 3 },]},{ c: $scope.onions },{c: [{ v: "Olives" }, { v: 31 }]}
```

Comment: Your HTML is broken. Try: `<div google-chart chart="myChartObject" style="width:100%;"></div>`

Comment: no bro its not working

Comment: i used its from AGC code this is the url   http://angular-google-chart.github.io/angular-google-chart/docs/latest/examples/column/

Comment: hey bro, @victor175 is right `<div google-chart chart="myChartObject" width:100%;"></div>` is NOT valid HTML...look at your link again

Comment: ya its working thank q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div google-chart chart="myChartObject" style="width:100%;" ng-controller="GenericChartCtrl">

</div>
```

Try this i hope it will work